# can i use docker runtime feature of hadoop yarn in older version (hadoop 2.7.3)

Tags: docker, hadoop, hadoop-yarn

Yarn provides a feature to use linux executor container with the docker runtime , earlier yarn provides a functionality to create docker executor container instead of linux executor container , so i want to know if the new feature of docker runtime is backward compatible .

docker runtime that was introduced in the later version of hadoop to over come the shortcoming of docker executor container discussed below :

the bigger architectural issue is that in YARN, you can use one ContainerExecutor per NodeManager. All tasks will use the ContainerExecutor specified in the node’s configuration. As a result, once the cluster was configured to use DockerContainerExecutor, users would be unable to launch regular MapReduce, Tez, or Spark jobs. Additionally, implementing a new ContainerExecutor means that all of the benefits of the existing LinuxContainerExecutor (such as cgroups and traffic shaping) now need to be reimplemented in the new ContainerExecutor. As a result of these challenges, DockerContainerExecutor has been deprecated in favor of a newer abstraction – container runtimes – and DockerContainerExecutor will be removed in a future Apache Hadoop release.

Can i use the yarn docker runtime in older versions of hadoop (2.7.3).

Comment: What exactly do you mean "backwards compatible"? You will only have one version of Docker-related executor classes on your YARN classpath

Comment: i mean can i use the docker runtime feature  (that was introduced in the later version of hadoop to over come the shortcoming of docker executor container ) with the older version of hadoop (2.7.3) . the problems with docker container executors are added to the question now

Comment: You'd need to upgrade Hadoop in order use classes that are only available in newer versions, unless you plan to backport those features yourself into the older versions and recompile Hadoop.